# search the records using two keys in two tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have models named User and Service

User model has the following columns: `user_name` and `location_name`

Service model has the following columns: `user_location` and `service_name`

Now i want to search for the Users who are residing in a particular location and providing a particular service.

The main problem is a user can provide more than one service.

I have achieved the functionality in the following way:

```
serv1 = Services.find_by_service_name(service_name)

res = []
serv1.each do |s|
   res.push s if s.user_location == location_name
end
```

Can anybody suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> user can provide more than one service

That means `User` is associated to `Service` model with `has_many` relationship, i.e., your models should look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  ## ... 
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ## ...
end
```

Next, you must have a foreign_key `user_id` in `services` table.

> Now i want to search for the Users who are residing in a particular
>   location and providing a particular service.

You can achieve this result with the below mentioned query. Make sure to set the local variables `location_name` and `service_name` before executing this query:

```
User.joins(:services).where('users.location_name = ? and services.service_name = ?', location_name ,service_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're storing a field from the user model in the service model. I'm not sure this is advisable.

The `user` has a `location_name`. The `service` references an entire row in the `user` table, not a column, which is what `location_name` is. You can then interact with all aspects of a specific `service`'s `user`. Additionally, since you stated that a user can provide more than one service, we can assume that more than one user can provide same service. The `user` must also reference it's `services`.

With the above structure, your solution can then be:

```
matched_users = User
  .find_by_location_name(location_name)
  .select { |user| user.service_names.include?(desired_service) }
```

This will perform one query on your database, `User.find_by_location(location_name)`, which will return users from your desired location. We can then call the [ruby enum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) method `select`, from which we select the users that provide our desired service.